# How can I damage the Epiphany boss?

Tags: bit-trip-flux

[image: The epiphany boss]

It's clear that in order to beat this boss I need to hit the red block on the opposite side of the field. No matter what I've tried, no matter how angled my shots, however, I haven't been able to take even a single block from his field. If I hit it with the corner of my paddle, the boss hits it with the corner of HIS paddle. The ball never speeds up. Apparently this [might be a known issue?](https://steamcommunity.com/app/205090/discussions/0/458606877323792609/)